# How to implement 3d effect or MKMapCamera functionality in MKMapview in ios6

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit

i am using MKMapCamera in iOS 7 for 3D effect for my navigation type application but i am not able to set 3D in iOS 6 Map and also not able to find any solution for giving effect like MKMapCamera in iOS 6 Map.

Can anybody guide for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D mode came with IOS7, you cannot use that mode in IOS6.

Answer (score -2):

No, you'd have to write our own map renderer from scratch.